# Will I need to create a virtualenv every time I runserver with Django?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, cs50

Currently taking CS50 Web Programming with Python and Javascript. I'm on the Week 3 Django lecture and trying to follow along but I'm running into trouble while trying to run python manage.py run server.

I'm getting the "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?" error.

I'm using Windows, Django IS installed and I've reinstalled it multiple times. I've found a workaround by following the steps from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJdfsrvnhTE&t=296s to set up a virtual env and can proceed after that, but in the lecture Brian doesn't need to setup a virtual env? It just loads straight through for him?

Yes I have scoured through reddit, stackoverflow, youtube, and other articles online before asking this here. It's not too much trouble to do so but I'm just wondeirng why he didn't need to make a virtualenv and if I'm actually going to have to make a virtual env for every Django project going forward? Is it because things have changed with python/pip/Django?

I would just find it more convenient if I could just run the run server command without having to run the extra 4 commands to setup the virtual env before being able to runserver.

Any info or guidance on this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I have a workaround. I'm just wondering why in the lecture he didn't need to create a virtual env for it to work.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "the extra 4 commands to setup the virtual env"? (We're not going to watch a YouTube video to understand your question.) TL;DR: you don't need to, and shouldn't, create a new virtual environment every time. You _do_ need to _activate_ your environment somehow. Depending on your preferred toolchain, there are several ways to accomplish that.

Comment: It should only be a single command to run. From the project directory, you just need to run `./venv/Scripts/activate` (one of them).

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not. In fact, you don't HAVE to use one at all, but it's a good practice to set up a virtual environment for each of your projects because not all modules play well together.

Creating the virtual environment is generally the first step when you start to build a project. The second step will then be to activate that virtual environment. You'll use pip to install modules like Django into that environment. This has the effect of essentially creating your own little custom version of python under the directory you chose for your virtual environment which you will then use the modules from and add modules to (with pip) while building your project.

To launch the django server you run the line: `python manage.py runserver` from your console. I use Pycharm as my IDE which simplifies all of this stuff and also allows me to launch runserver and open the browser with just a click. I would recommend downloading it and taking a look at it. I'm sure it would help get you a little further along.

Answer (score -1):

Run this command to check that Django is correctly installed and accessible from your current directory
`python -m django --version`
If everything is working correctly should see the version of your installation

Run this command from the outer "projectName" directory
`python manage.py runserver`

It would be more helpful to read the official documentation from Django.

Official Django ~5min tutorial 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/ 
Django Installation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/install/

Please remember these instructions are not system, editor, or IDE specific you can run the commands from your terminal and use any system, editor, or IDE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to actually address the question being asked when posting answers.